# OpenCV in WebAssembly compiling issue

Tags: c++, opencv, webassembly

I am trying to compile a C++ script that uses OpenCV into WebAssembly. When compiling normally I use:

```
g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4) -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main
```

So for WASM I tried to use:

```
em++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4) -std=c++11 main.cpp -s WASM=1 -o main.html
```

However I get a ton of warnings and then some errors at the end. Below is an excerpt.

Warnings are like:

> shared:WARNING: object
>   /var/folders/49/4k6th5hd1f5dz15hdvjltm4h0000gn/T/emscripten_temp_cjgkv8_archive_contents/sum.avx2.cpp.o
>   is not a valid object file for emscripten, cannot link

Errors are like:

> error: undefined symbol:
>   _ZN2cv14findHomographyERKNS_11_InputArrayES2_idRKNS_12_OutputArrayEid

My guess is it is not able to compile the OpenCV files into WASM for some reason and so ignoring them then having issues when references are made to what should have been compiled. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you managed to ever solve this issue? I'd be interested in how it was resolved

Comment: @Tamas yes was able to fix this. It was crazy complicated! Can't remember exactly because this project was a while back. If you are struggling with something similar, lmk and I'll try and help :)

Comment: sorry I completely missed your response. I have managed to solve it as well - I ended up writing a 15 page long document about the process lol

Comment: @AntersBear I am having the same problem, could you provide some more info, please?

Comment: @HarryR. I can't remember exactly but it was super complicated and you're going to have to go into the python compiler script to fix it